# Workflow fails with "The email message cannot be sent. Make sure that the email has a valid recipient."

Tags: workflow

The workflow is kicked off by a retention policy so it is started by SHAREPOINT/SYSTEM. I have seen several posts on this issue but no answers that really help in this case.

Basically it is being asked to used the Content Owner column (People or Groups) to return the email address. That email address is what it is supposed to be using to send. When done manually with me as the initiator it works perfectly. When the system account does it, it fails.

I have seen a post that said you could add the email address into the table in SQL however Microsoft may not cover your installation anymore if you do that so I really don't want to do that. I am curious if there is a way to manually set the workflow initiator or some other work around. I am about ready to call Microsoft to see how they would remedy this issue. I just hate to spend the $250 if somebody has figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this action while impersonating a user that does have an email address.  If you are doing a C# workflow, see http://blackninjasoftware.com/2009/04/09/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/ for how to impersonate a user in code.

For SharePoint Designer, you can use an Impersonation Step.

Comment: I tried that. I added an impersonation step with my account and I do have a good email address. However it still fails. It is using SHAREPOINT/SYSTEM to initiate the workflow and that account does not have an email address. Unfortunately even with the workflow running under my credentials, it is still started by the system account, and the system account is what attempts to send the email.